# Data structures - Queue

Tags: data-structures, queue

I have queue q of integer numbers stored in an array in the circular fashion
from front to rear that is..

```
f:      1
r:      8
array Q: 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
           2 8 4 4 3 5 4
```

What is the array representation of queue q after i perform the following?

while `q.front()` is an even number do `q.enqueue(q.dequeue())`.

Comment: Is this homework? If so, please tag it [tag:homework] so that is apparent to others.

Comment: What is your solution? What exactly do you have problems with?

Answer (score 0):

It will loop until it reaches number 3. So the array will be

> ```
> 0 1 2 3 4 5 6 7 8 9
>
> 4 4       3 5 4 2 8
> ```